# what is wrong with function ? (beginner in python)

Tags: python

```
  s='insert 0 5 insert 1 10 insert 0 6 print remove 6 append 9 append 1 sort print'
  y=(s.split())

  i=[]

def commands(str_):
  if str_==[]:
    return[]
  elif str_[0]=='insert':
    return i.insert(int (str_[1]), str_[2]) + commands(str_[3:])
  elif str_[0]=='print':
    print (i) + commands(str_[1:])
  elif str_[0]=='append':
    return i.append(str_[1]) + commands(str_[2:])
  elif str_[0]=='remove':
    return i.pop(1) + commands(str_[2:])
  elif str_[0]=='sort':
    return i.sort() + commands(str_[1:])
  elif str_[0]=='pop':
    return i.pop() + commands(str_[1:])
  elif str_[0]=='reverse':
    return i.reverse()
print(commands (y))
```

hi, guys, I'm a beginner at python and was playing around with it and making my own function. 
this function takes in a list of strings as commands and produces those commands, however, when I try to run this function this shows up
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
what is wrong with my function?

Comment: Most list methods, those that modify the list, return `None`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what can i do to change that ? I'm a beginner so I don't know which list functions return none

Comment: To add to the comment above: instead of `return i.insert(...)` you should do `i.insert(...)` followed by `return i`, etc.

Comment: pop, print and sort don't return anything so you can't add them with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an entire list to a function is counter-intuitive to me. One cleaner approach would be to iterate over the list of command values like below

```
new_list= []
for idx,command in enumerate(y):
    if command == 'insert':
        index = int(y[idx+1])
        value_to_insert = int(y[idx+2])
        new_list.insert(index,value_to_insert)

    elif command == 'print':
        print(new_list)

    elif command == 'append':
        value_to_append = int(y[idx+1])
        new_list.append(value_to_append)

    elif command == 'sort':
        new_list.sort() # inplace sorting

    elif command == 'remove':
        item_index = new_list.index(int(y[idx+1])) #multiple values can be present
        new_list.pop(item_index)

    elif command == 'pop':
        new_list.pop()

    elif command == 'reverse':
        new_list = new_list[::-1]
```